# How to align 4 containers side by side in css?

Tags: html, css

I need to align 12 buttons so that there are 4 buttons on the top and 3 on the sides (12). 4x3
Also 2 more buttons at the top left (Div/Mult) and right (Add/Sub)

I will include the HTML and CSS document and if you need the JS document, please do not hesitate to ask.
This is how I want it to look, and I do not know how.

Div/MultBtn                                                    Add/SubBtn

1            2           3        4 (all the way to the other side)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Math Fact Tune Up</title>

  <style>
    #buttonContainer {
      position: relative;
      top: 50%;
      transform: translateY(-50%);
    }
    button {
      display: block;
      margin: 0 auto;
      background-color: #262b2b;
      border-style: solid;
      color: white;
      font-family: Open Sans, sans-serif;
      border-radius: 5px;
    }
    .lvlButton {
      padding-bottom: .1em;
      padding-top: .1em;
    }
    body,
    html {
      height: 100%;
      overflow: scroll;
      overflow-x: hidden;
      background-color: #262b2b;
    }
    body {
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    #go {
      background-color: #00d10d
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>


  <div id="buttonContainer">
    <div class="lvlButton" id="divMult">
      <button id="divMultBtn">
        Multiplication/Division
      </button>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="lvlButton" id="addSub">
      <button id="addSubBtn">
        Addition/Subtraction
      </button>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="lvlButton" id="lvl1">
      <button id="lvl1Btn">
        Level 1
      </button>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="lvlButton" id="lvl2">
      <button id="lvl2Btn">
        Level 2
      </button>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="lvlButton" id="lvl3">
      <button id="lvl3Btn">
        Level 3
      </button>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="lvlButton" id="lvl4">
      <button id="lvl4Btn">
        Level 4
      </button>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="lvlButton" id="lvl5">
      <button id="lvl5Btn">
        Level 5
      </button>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="lvlButton" id="lvl6">
      <button id="lvl6Btn">
        Level 6
      </button>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="lvlButton" id="lvl7">
      <button id="lvl7Btn">
        Level 7
      </button>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="lvlButton" id="lvl8">
      <button id="lvl8Btn">
        Level 8
      </button>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="lvlButton" id="lvl9">
      <button id="lvl9Btn">
        Level 9
      </button>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="lvlButton" id="lvl10">
      <button id="lvl10Btn">
        Level 10
      </button>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="lvlButton" id="lvl11">
      <button id="lvl11Btn">
        Level 11
      </button>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="lvlButton" id="lvl12">
      <button id="lvl12Btn">
        Level 12
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="lvlButton" id="gocontainer">
      <button id="go">
        GO
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>


</body>

</html>
```

Picture of result

[image]

Comment: _"and 3 on the sides"_ What do you mean by "on the sides"?

Comment: @guest271314 I mean going vertical. I tried portraying it but it removed my spaces. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: have you tried absolute positioning inside the container?

Comment: @Bindrid I'm really new to html and css (my friend isn't available to help me) and I wanted to make an web app (because I know js) so I do not know how to do that

Comment: I just posted my answer. Feel free to copy paste the source code. It should be working as expected.

Comment: I don't understand how you want the result to look like..?

Comment: If you plan to spend more time coding, studying and understanding CSS will pay big dividends.

Comment: @Bindrid Alright will do! Thank you!

Comment: I would like to note that you should start with `clear property`. When you have bunch of things floating on the screen you will run in some troubles soon. Just use `clear: left/right/both` when you need to stop the floating.

Comment: @Michal Will do, thank you for the help! Excited to use html and css more often.

Comment: @ethanlee What is purpose of image following _"Picture of result"_ at Question? Is rendering elements consistent with  image at Question not actually the expected result? Is the image at Question erroneous and to be ignored as to actual requirement of Question?

Comment: @ethanlee Not following progression of Question to accepted Answer. The text description of expected result _"I need to align 12 buttons so that there are 4 buttons on the top and 3 on the sides (12). 4x3 Also 2 more buttons at the top left (Div/Mult) and right (Add/Sub)"_ , the image following _"Picture of result"_ and rendered `html` `document` at stacksnippets at accepted Answer are not consistent.

Comment: @guest271314 The picture in the original question is what it currently was, but I fixed it.

Comment: @ethanlee Still not following. _"The picture in the original question is what it currently was, but I fixed it."_ The `html` and `css` at original Question do not render the same as image.  Why did you include text _"Picture of result"_ at Question?  Why do you mean by "I fixed it"? What did you "fix"? What is "it"? Even if image is omitted from the progression, the result at stacksnippets at accepted Answer is not consistent with the actual text description of expected result at Question _"I need to align 12 buttons so that there are 4 buttons on the top and 3 on the sides"_

Comment: @ethanlee It should be self-evident that one or all of components of Question and accepted Answer are not consistent. The image at OP is  not relevant to actual `html` and `css` at Question or expected result. Have you considered editing Question to remove image and describe actual expected result?

Comment: @guest271314 It was what I would originally get with the code in the question. Since then, I have changed it.

Comment: @ethanlee _"It was what I would originally get with the code in the question. Since then, I have changed it"_ How is image related to actual `html`, `css` at Question if the `html`, `css` do not render the `document` with `css` applied to equal image rendition? Is requirement  _"I need to align 12 buttons so that there are 4 buttons on the top and 3 on the sides"_?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want something to float you need to:

1. Set position: relative
2. Set float: left

Why would you have `<br />` tag after each div? This should be working:

```css
#buttonContainer {
      position: relative;
      top: 50%;
      transform: translateY(-50%);

    }
    button{
         display: block;
         margin: 0 auto;
         background-color: #262b2b;
         border-style: solid;
         color: white;
         font-family: Open Sans, sans-serif;
         border-radius: 5px;
    }

    .lvlButton{
         padding-bottom: .1em;
         padding-top:.1em;
         float: left;

    }

    body, html{
         height:100%;
         overflow: scroll;
         overflow-x: hidden;
         background-color: #262b2b;
    }
    body{
         overflow: hidden;
    }

    #go{
         background-color: #00d10d
    }
```

```html
<div id="buttonContainer">
 <div class="lvlButton" id="divMult">
 <button id="divMultBtn">
    Multiplication/Division
   </button>
 </div>
<div class="lvlButton" id="addSub">
 <button id="addSubBtn">
   Addition/Subtraction
  </button>
 </div>
<div class="lvlButton" id="lvl1">
 <button id="lvl1Btn">
   Level 1
  </button>
 </div>
<div class="lvlButton" id="lvl2">
 <button id="lvl2Btn">
   Level 2
  </button>
 </div>
<div class="lvlButton" id="lvl3">
 <button id="lvl3Btn">
   Level 3
  </button>
 </div>
 <div class="lvlButton" id="lvl4">
  <button id="lvl4Btn">
   Level 4
  </button>
 </div>
 <div class="lvlButton" id="lvl5">
 <button id="lvl5Btn">
   Level 5
  </button> 
 </div>
  <div class="lvlButton" id="lvl6">
 <button id="lvl6Btn">
   Level 6
  </button> 
 </div>
  <div class="lvlButton" id="lvl7">
 <button id="lvl7Btn">
   Level 7
  </button> 
 </div>
  <div class="lvlButton" id="lvl8">
 <button id="lvl8Btn">
   Level 8
  </button> 
 </div>
  <div class="lvlButton" id="lvl9">
 <button id="lvl9Btn">
   Level 9
  </button> 
 </div>
  <div class="lvlButton" id="lvl10">
 <button id="lvl10Btn">
   Level 10
  </button> 
 </div>
  <div class="lvlButton" id="lvl11">
 <button id="lvl11Btn">
   Level 11
  </button> 
 </div>
  <div class="lvlButton" id="lvl12">
 <button id="lvl12Btn">
   Level 12
  </button>
 </div>
 <div class="lvlButton" id="gocontainer">
 <button id ="go">
   GO
  </button>
 </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: I just moved the code to snippet. You should be able to run the code on stackoverflow now.

Comment: Oh sorry, my bad! Thank you so much!! I marked you as the right answer!! thank you!

Comment: @ethanlee The rendered result at stacksnippets at Answer is not equal to image at OP?

Comment: He obviously wanted to have them in one row.

Comment: @Michal Image at OP is erroneous and to be ignored as to requirement?